# Vuejs v-on:click not working on option tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, directive

I am trying to make a vueapp that sets a property when the user clicks on an option tag. I'm trying to use v-on:click but it hasn't worked. Any ideas?

```xml
<div v-show="loggedin==1" class="searchBy">
    <h2>Selected Display</h2>
    <select v-model="selectedDisplayShapeText">
        <option value="" disabled>Please Choose One</option>
        <option v-for="display in displays" :value="display.shapetext" v-on:click="displayName=display.name">{{display.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select-Options It seems like you should be using `v-bind:value="{ displayName:display.name }"` instead of `v-on:click`

Comment: I understand that I can do that I am doing already with <option v-for="display in displays" :value="display.shapetext"> however when they click on an option I would also like to set another property and or run a function

Comment: Ah, then you probably want to bind to `change`, not `click`: `<select v-on:change="displayName=display.name"`

Comment: Instead of `:value=display.shapetext`, bind the value to `display` and change bind your model to a selected display property (like `v-model="selectedDisplay"`). Then, whenever you need either of the display properties, just reference them from `selectedDisplay`.

Comment: tried that no luck <select v-model="selectedDisplayShapeText" v-on:select="displayName=display.name">
            <option value="" disabled>Please Choose One</option>
          <option v-for="display in displays" :value="display.shapetext">{{display.name}}</option>
          </select>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the option on the `change` event of select:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      displays: [{ name: "Display1", shapetext: "1" }, { name: "Display2", shapetext: "2" }, { name: "Display3", shapetext: "3" }],
      selectedDisplayShapeText: '',
      displayName: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDisplayName(e){
      let value = e.target.value
      let display = this.displays.find(d => d.shapetext == value)
      this.displayName = display.name
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Selected Display</h2>
  <select v-model="selectedDisplayShapeText" v-on:change="getDisplayName($event)">
    <option value="" disabled>Please Choose One</option>
    <option v-for="display in displays" :value="display.shapetext">{{display.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <p>Display selected: {{ displayName }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the value of a select option in Vue to a complex expression (in this case an object).

Instead of binding your selected option to a property of the display object, just bind it to the display object itself. Then, whenever you need one of the properties of the selected display, you can just reference them from the selected display.

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    displays: [
      {shapetext: "shape text 1", name: "display one"},
      {shapetext: "shape text 2", name: "display two"},
      {shapetext: "shape text 3", name: "display three"},
      
    ],
    selectedDisplay: {}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Selected Display</h2>
      <select v-model="selectedDisplay">
      <option value="" disabled>Please Choose One</option>
    <option v-for="display in displays" :value="display" >{{display.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    Selected Display shapetext: {{selectedDisplay.shapetext}} <br>
    Selected Display name: {{selectedDisplay.name}}
</div>
```